# DropDownLists Value Resetting

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList populated with a set of values. When I click a value, the DropDownList value should stay to that value, but it resets to the default value (Select a Type) most of the time.

Here is the DDL:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Criteria Type:" SortExpression="CriteriaType">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="CriteriaType" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CriteriaType") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select a Type</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="TMEL Table">TMEL Table</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Risk Matrix">Risk Matrix</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Alarm Rationalization">Alarm Rationalization</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="CriteriaType" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CriteriaType") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select a Type</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="TMEL Table">TMEL Table</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Risk Matrix">Risk Matrix</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Alarm Rationalization">Alarm Rationalization</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CriteriaType") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList criteriaType = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("CriteriaType");
        if (criteriaType.SelectedValue == "TMEL Table")
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = false;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = false;

        }
        else if ((criteriaType.SelectedValue == "Risk Matrix"))
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[8].Visible = true;
        }
        else if ((criteriaType.SelectedValue == "Alarm Rationalization"))
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[8].Visible = true;
        }
        else if (criteriaType.SelectedValue == "Select a Type")
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = false;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = false;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you add check if it not postback

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if(!IsPostBack)
       {
        DropDownList criteriaType = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("CriteriaType");
        if (criteriaType.SelectedValue == "TMEL Table")
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = false;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = false;

        }
        else if ((criteriaType.SelectedValue == "Risk Matrix"))
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[8].Visible = true;
        }
        else if ((criteriaType.SelectedValue == "Alarm Rationalization"))
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = true;
            DetailsView1.Fields[8].Visible = true;
        }
        else if (criteriaType.SelectedValue == "Select a Type")
        {
            DetailsView1.Fields[5].Visible = false;
            DetailsView1.Fields[6].Visible = false;
            DetailsView1.Fields[7].Visible = false;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The value of the DropDownList now sticks, but there is no manipulation of the fields. When I click any DDL value, none of the DetailsView1 fields that are supposed to be visible become visible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how the IsPostBack event works and Page state? basically the controls refresh when the IsPostBack event works.

Every time that you update the page from the codebehind, a magic little piece of Javascript is fired which either hits the server through an XMLHTTTP post ( I think ) or a true hard post back hits the server, like a form post. So when the server see this it checks for the IsPostBack flag, it is like an automatic field that is added to every ASP.net page.

Then you check the IsPostBack flag to change the state of things.

If you populate your list box in the IsPostBack=true, it won't appear to be selectable. If you populate your ListBox without it, it will appear that the value keeps changing.

This may be as simple as setting the selcted value in the PostBack.

HTH